# Probability of rescue

Tags: probability, self-study

A mountain climber has been lost on a mountain on either slope A or slope B. The head of the rescue mission believes that the mountain climber is on A with probability 0.6. Suppose she has 12 rescue parties which are all equally competent and will locate the climber with a probability .3 if they are on the correct slope. Suppose they work independently of each other.
If the mission leader sends 8 teams to slope A and 4 teams to slope B, what is the probability that they rescue the climber?

Here's my train of thought: What they need is for 1 team to at least rescue the mountain climber, so I can just take $ 1- P(\textrm{no Teams Rescued)}$, to which $ P(\textrm{no Teams Rescued}) = ((0.6)(0.7))^8 + ((0.4)(0.7))^4 . $

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my way of thinking? The correct answer results to $ .87.$

Comment: A more interesting question is the optimal number of people to assign to each team.

Comment: @wolfies it is, but it seems to be homework and we don't have much information. Notice that they assigned 0.6 (rounded up) of available resources to the more promising slope. A priori it is a quite good choice with this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct but you used $0.3$ as the probability of “no success” while it should be $1-0.3=0.7$. If you swap the numbers you'll get the correct result. You also used unnecessary braces there. The calculation becomes

$$
1-(0.6 \times 0.7^8 + 0.4 \times 0.7^4) \approx 0.87
$$

With your braces, it was as if each of the rescue parties could succeed on either of the slopes, while it's $8$ and $4$ parties assigned to the slopes and the probabilities of success of the expeditions.

Comment: Hey Tim, sorry I placed the wrong number, but it should be 0.7 instead. But it still doesnt result in the answer provided as mentioned in the book, or is the book wrong by any chance?

Comment: @sasaasasasha check my edit.

Comment: Ah I see, I genuinely thought that it was $(0.6 * 0.7)^8$ instead of just $0.6 * (0.7)^8$, thank you so much